# Why do I keep getting an error?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, integer, double

```
public static void add3(ArrayList<Integer> a)
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = console.nextInt();
    a.add(i);
    i = console.nextInt();
    a.add(i);
    i = console.nextInt();
    a.add(i);
}
public static void add3(ArrayList<Double> a)
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    double i = console.nextDouble();
    a.add(i);
    i = console.nextDouble();
    a.add(i);
    i = console.nextDouble();
    a.add(i);
}
```

When I run my program, the Integer version works, however the Double version does not. It keeps giving me an error that says the type is not applicable to add3(ArrayList a). This is confusing me because there is still another method with the type double, but it seems as if the complier cannot see it. Any suggestions on how to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: How are you _calling_ these methods?

Comment: surely due to type erasure

Comment: Because : Type erasure. Those two methods have the same signature.

Comment: In other words try to rename one method.

Answer (score 1):

As the [tutorial from Oracles states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html), this doesn't work due to type easure:

> A class cannot have two overloaded methods that will have the same
>   signature after type erasure.

```
public class Example {
    public void print(Set<String> strSet) { }
    public void print(Set<Integer> intSet) { } }
```

> The overloads would all share the same classfile representation and will generate a compile-time error.

After type erasure both methods take a `Set` as their single argument and can not be distinguished from each other.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar It wouldn't. I suspect the OP doesn't understand the difference between a compile time error and a runtime error - they're just pushing the "run" button in their IDE.

Comment: Ok, how would I fix it while keeping them overloaded (I don't want to change the name)?

Comment: @user3396838 You ... can't. That's not the way Java works. You can't have two methods with the same name that take the same arguments, which after type erasure is what you have.